# LINQ - Include Child Property of Child Property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a child property of a child property in my entity. I have a Get method as such:

```
List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, 
             params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] toInclude);
```

The way I normally load just the first child property is to do this:

```
myManager.Find(x => x.Id == id, x.ChildB);
```

However, I would like to be able to pull back the ChildC property which is a child of my ChildB property.

Is there anyway to perform this with the method signature I provided? I know normally I could do a .Include("ChildB.ChildC").

Edit: Added code per request

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = (ObjectQuery<T>)context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    foreach(var include in toInclude)
    {
        objectQuery = objectQuery.Include(include);
    }

    return objectQuery.Where<T>(where);
}
```

Comment: brandon - any chance you could also include the implementation of the List<T> Find() method stub?? given that, I'm sure i could make a decent stab at the problem. thanks...

Comment: ok -gotcha, will take a look over it and see if i can 'add value'..

Comment: brandon - i'm afraid i couldn't find a way to meet your requirement on this one. quite a tough one really. might be a case of downloading the EF source (if it's available) or running it under reflector and looking at what happens when you try to include the childb.childc scenario (i'm sure this has occurred to you, but just in case)). again sorry to have come up 'limp lettuce' on this one it seemed like quite a straightfwd challenge..

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about LINQ-to-SQL, then you would configure the DataContext before executing any queries against it.

Something like:

```
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<ChildB>(b => b.ChildC);
dataContext.LoadOptions = options;
```

Comment: I am doing LINQ-to-Entities, however, I was hoping that the developer could pass a list of Navigation Properties they wanted to include without having to deal with the Context.